# PDFTK fill_form (fdf) with any kind of image

Tags: pdftk

I'm very new in using PDFTK, but I know, how to generate a .fdf-file, fill it manual and put it back in the pdf-file by the fill_form-command.

But now, I don't want to fill the fields with text, but with an image.
Is there any way to do this with PDFTK?

I hope, you can understand, what I mean and what I want to do.
Thanks for help!

[See the image as explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN6H7.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything? You need to give it a go urself before asking.

Comment: PdfTk is nothing more than an obsolete iText version (dating from 2009) compiled to a binary executable using GCJ. Back in 2009, iText wasn't able to meet your requirement, hence PdfTk isn't able to meet your requirement. You'll need to use another tool.

Comment: @Kenneth, no, I don't try anything, because I don't know how... I have no idea, if this is possible at all. So I only could give you the image below.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, is there really no way to do this??
Can you recommend another tool for what I want...??

Comment: I create a button field as a placeholder for an image. Then I use iText (java) to replace the "icon" of the button field. If you don't know how to program in Java, you can use iTextSharp (C#). If you don't know Java or C#, you'll have to continue your search.